# A matrix lies in a subring isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory

**Problem:**

> Consider the matrix $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 3\\ -4 & 1
>  \end{pmatrix}.$$ Show that $A$ lies in a subring of Mat$_{2\times
>  2}(\mathbb{R})$ that is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$.

**My idea:**
We show that $A = CDC^{-1}$ where D is in the form of 
$$D = \begin{pmatrix} a & -b\\ b& a\end{pmatrix}.$$
It is easy to see that all elements as such form a subring of $Mat_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R})$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$. Using the fact that $\det(A) = \det(D)$ and $tr(A) =tr(D)$ we obtain that $a = 1/2$ and $b = \sqrt{47/4}$. We can then search for $C$. Set

$$C = \begin{pmatrix} u_1 & u_2\\ u_3 & u_4\end{pmatrix},$$
and solve for $AC = CD$ we arrive at

$$\begin{pmatrix}1/2 & 4 & -\sqrt{47/4} & 0\\ 3 & 1/2 & 0 & \sqrt{47/4}\\ \sqrt{47/4} & 0 & 1/2 & 4\\ 0 & \sqrt{47/4} & -3 & -1/2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}u_1\\u_2\\u_3\\u_4\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}.$$
Since the left matrix has rank 2, the solution space is 2 dimensional, and we can find one such that $ad-bc\ne 0$.

**Question:**
Is my solution correct? What is a simpler proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial of $A$, which is also the minimal polynomial, is $p(\lambda) = \lambda^2 - \lambda + 12 = 
(\lambda - 1/2)^2 + 47/4$.  So in any correspondence between the subring and the complex numbers, $A$ should correspond to a complex number $\omega$ with $(\omega - 1/2)^2 + 47/4 = 0$.  We can take $\omega = \dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{\sqrt{47} }{2} i$.  Take the subring to be the linear span (over $\mathbb R$) of $I$ and $A$, and
the isomorphism from this to $\mathbb C$ is $aI + bA \mapsto a + b \omega$.